# How to describe a methodology that infers objects' unobserved properties from their similarity to simulations

Tags: regression, bayesian, terminology

I am trying to succinctly describe a technique I've developed for inferring some unobserved properties of galaxies based on their observed similarity to simulations.

I have a bunch of simulated galaxies ("models") with randomized properties. For each model, I'm able to calculate an observable (the galaxies' light, $F_i$) as well as an unobservable quantity ($Z_i$).

For a single observed galaxy whose value of $Z$ I want to estimate, I have measured the observable ($G_j$), which allows me to calculate the likelihood of each model observable $F_i$ given $G_j$. I estimate the credible interval of the observed galaxy's true value of $Z$ according to the models' distribution of $Z$ modulated by individual model likelihoods. In a sense, the models function like a prior on the permitted values of $Z$, and the observations refine that knowledge.

I tried to describe this approach to a colleague as Bayesian-like simulation-based regression, but I realize this is (a) cumbersome, and (b) not really precise. Is there a recognized term for an approach like this?

Here's an example:

```
z_model = [ 0.96604083,  0.8950759 ,  0.26739221,  0.78885513,  0.46864461,
           -0.89459213,  0.32510295,  0.27743712,  0.80906217, -1.65347359,
           -0.35529047, -0.84560544, -0.60275437, -0.51915018, -0.06279448,
           -0.70864864, -1.00294815,  1.54111973,  0.91869118, -1.0194281 ]
f_model = [0.43903895, 0.38699154, 0.81685133, 0.42837242, 0.53471571,
           2.50768834, 0.67949965, 0.8649594 , 0.49804382, 5.27470087,
           1.44470055, 2.3652452 , 1.90566768, 1.64401882, 1.06186624,
           2.02989631, 2.70800674, 0.27957155, 0.3578594 , 2.85373388]
g_obs = 0.3
g_obs_unc = 0.25
likelihoods = [1.36711298e+00, 1.50202711e+00, 1.88298554e-01, 1.39866749e+00,
               1.02698168e+00, 1.85929953e-17, 5.04189032e-01, 1.24173298e-01,
               1.16600687e+00, 1.66276807e-86, 4.47079616e-05, 2.42112034e-15,
               1.75992677e-09, 8.45162566e-07, 1.53572830e-02, 6.39465187e-11,
               1.14006603e-20, 1.59045041e+00, 1.55359896e+00, 3.50559077e-23]
```

In this case, the 5th to 95th percentile credible interval is `[.325, 1.54]`

Comment: sounds vaguely like [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_Bayesian_computation#The_ABC_rejection_algorithm)? although i'm not an expert in this area, so could be wrong.

Comment: ABC seems like a good approximate description, yes